# How to execute multiple SP inside another SP and return its responses?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have this situation:

I need to execute 3 stored procedures that return the same information but each one have its own logic, validations and searches the info in different tables. I want to create a new SP that executes the other three ones and return the results of that ones.

I tried with custom datatype and return a table, or just return the three datatype objects but the SP just doesn't return anyting despite at least one of the stored procedures found information, and it doesn't throw an error to know what's happening.

This is my code until now:

```
/* These are the fields each SP returns */
TYPE RESULT_DOCUMENTO IS RECORD (
    P_NOMBRES VARCHAR2(80),
    P_PRIMER_APELLIDO VARCHAR2(30),
    P_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO VARCHAR2(30),
    P_FECHA_NACIMIENTO_SALIDA DATE,
    P_NACIONALIDAD_SALIDA VARCHAR2(200),
    P_TIPO_DOCUMENTO_SALIDA VARCHAR2(200),
    P_NUM_DOCUMENTO_SALIDA VARCHAR2(200),
    P_FECHA_EXPEDICION DATE,
    P_FECHA_VENCIMIENTO DATE,
    P_ESTADO VARCHAR2(200),
    P_SEXO VARCHAR2(1)
);


TYPE RESULT_DOCUMENTOS IS TABLE OF RESULT_DOCUMENTO INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;


/* This is the head of the new SP */
PROCEDURE PR_CONSULTAR_DOC_PPT_CE_PEP(
    P_TIPO_DOCUMENTO IN VARCHAR2,
    P_NUMERO_DOC IN VARCHAR2,
    P_FECHA_NACIMIENTO IN DATE,
    P_NACIONALIDAD IN VARCHAR2,
    P_TRAMITES IN VARCHAR2,
    /* This was my try of returning a table with the 3 results inside */
    --P_DOCUMENTOS OUT RESULT_DOCUMENTOS
    P_RESULT_PPT OUT RESULT_DOCUMENTO,
    P_RESULT_CE OUT RESULT_DOCUMENTO,
    P_RESULT_PEP OUT RESULT_DOCUMENTO
);
```

This is the body of the SP:

```
PROCEDURE PR_CONSULTAR_DOC_PPT_CE_PEP(
    P_TIPO_DOCUMENTO IN VARCHAR2,
    P_NUMERO_DOC IN VARCHAR2,
    P_FECHA_NACIMIENTO IN DATE,
    P_NACIONALIDAD IN VARCHAR2,
    P_TRAMITES IN VARCHAR2,
    --P_DOCUMENTOS OUT RESULT_DOCUMENTOS
    P_RESULT_PPT OUT RESULT_DOCUMENTO,
    P_RESULT_CE OUT RESULT_DOCUMENTO,
    P_RESULT_PEP OUT RESULT_DOCUMENTO
)
AS
    /* This code was in case I return the table and not each object individually */
    /*P_RESULT_PPT RESULT_DOCUMENTO;
    P_RESULT_CE RESULT_DOCUMENTO;
    P_RESULT_PEP RESULT_DOCUMENTO;*/
BEGIN

    -- First SP
    PR_CONSULTAR_DOC_PPT_GEN(
        P_TIPO_DOCUMENTO,
        P_NUMERO_DOC,
        P_FECHA_NACIMIENTO,
        P_NACIONALIDAD,
        P_TRAMITES,
        P_RESULT_PPT.P_NOMBRES,
        P_RESULT_PPT.P_PRIMER_APELLIDO,
        P_RESULT_PPT.P_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
        P_RESULT_PPT.P_FECHA_NACIMIENTO_SALIDA,
        P_RESULT_PPT.P_NACIONALIDAD_SALIDA,
        P_RESULT_PPT.P_TIPO_DOCUMENTO_SALIDA,
        P_RESULT_PPT.P_NUM_DOCUMENTO_SALIDA,
        P_RESULT_PPT.P_FECHA_EXPEDICION,
        P_RESULT_PPT.P_FECHA_VENCIMIENTO,
        P_RESULT_PPT.P_ESTADO,
        P_RESULT_PPT.P_SEXO
    );

    -- Second SP
    /*PR_CONSULTAR_DOC_CE_GEN(P_TIPO_DOCUMENTO,
        P_NUMERO_DOC,
        P_FECHA_NACIMIENTO,
        P_NACIONALIDAD,
        P_TRAMITES,
        P_RESULT_CE.P_NOMBRES,
        P_RESULT_CE.P_PRIMER_APELLIDO,
        P_RESULT_CE.P_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
        P_RESULT_CE.P_FECHA_NACIMIENTO_SALIDA,
        P_RESULT_CE.P_NACIONALIDAD_SALIDA,
        P_RESULT_CE.P_TIPO_DOCUMENTO_SALIDA,
        P_RESULT_CE.P_NUM_DOCUMENTO_SALIDA,
        P_RESULT_CE.P_FECHA_EXPEDICION,
        P_RESULT_CE.P_FECHA_VENCIMIENTO,
        P_RESULT_CE.P_ESTADO,
        P_RESULT_CE.P_SEXO
    );

    -- Third SP
    PR_CONSULTAR_PEP_GEN(P_TIPO_DOCUMENTO,
        P_NUMERO_DOC,
        P_FECHA_NACIMIENTO,
        P_NACIONALIDAD,
        P_RESULT_PEP.P_NOMBRES,
        P_RESULT_PEP.P_PRIMER_APELLIDO,
        P_RESULT_PEP.P_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
        P_RESULT_PEP.P_FECHA_NACIMIENTO_SALIDA,
        P_RESULT_PEP.P_NACIONALIDAD_SALIDA,
        P_RESULT_PEP.P_TIPO_DOCUMENTO_SALIDA,
        P_RESULT_PEP.P_NUM_DOCUMENTO_SALIDA,
        P_RESULT_PEP.P_FECHA_EXPEDICION,
        P_RESULT_PEP.P_FECHA_VENCIMIENTO,
        P_RESULT_PEP.P_ESTADO,
        P_RESULT_PEP.P_SEXO
    );*/
    
    /* Here I tried to fill a table with the result of the executed SP */
    --P_DOCUMENTOS(1) := P_RESULT_PPT;
    --P_DOCUMENTOS(2) := P_RESULT_CE;
    --P_DOCUMENTOS(3) := P_RESULT_PEP;
    
    /*EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        IF P_RESULT_PPT.P_NOMBRES IS NOT NULL THEN
            P_DOCUMENTOS(1) := P_RESULT_PPT;
        ELSE
            P_DOCUMENTOS(1) := null;
        END IF;
        
        IF P_RESULT_CE.P_NOMBRES IS NOT NULL THEN
            P_DOCUMENTOS(2) := P_RESULT_CE;
        ELSE
            P_DOCUMENTOS(2) := null;
        END IF;
        
        IF P_RESULT_PEP.P_NOMBRES IS NOT NULL THEN
            P_DOCUMENTOS(3) := P_RESULT_PEP;
        ELSE
            P_DOCUMENTOS(3) := null;
        END IF;*/
    

    /* Here I tried to validate that the table type was filled */
    /*DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('RESULT: ' || P_DOCUMENTOS(1).P_NOMBRES);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('RESULT: ' || P_DOCUMENTOS(2).P_NOMBRES);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('RESULT: ' || P_DOCUMENTOS(3).P_NOMBRES);*/

END PR_CONSULTAR_DOC_PPT_CE_PEP;
```

Thank you for your attention, each commentary will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** This is a test I made only executing one of the three SP. I printed if the field "P_NOMBRES" is filled and it shows the result I expected, and the SP doesn't fail (doesn't show an oracle error or something similar).

[image: test result]

But here it shows empty the output variables, so it doesn't return the table of objects I created. Same happens if I try to return just the object datatype and not the table.

[image: test result 2]

Comment: How do you know the procedure doesn't return anything?  Can you share the code and results from the call to your procedure?

Comment: Thank you @Del I already updated the question with more information.